# Enable Auto-acceptance to Cases but not for Chats in Omnichannel

Tags: omnichannel, chat, case-object

We are trying to enable auto-acceptance of workitems to a group of service resources, but with the restriction that Chat cases should not be auto-accepted.

Current implementation :

1. Auto-Acceptance of cases setting enabled for the group in the presence configuration level.
2. Auto-acceptance of cases from chat button settings as disabled.

Other possibilities tried :

1. Enabled Auto acceptance at Service channel, but this enables auto-acceptance for all the users accepting items from this channel.

We are trying to find a solution where one type of workitems can be excluded from auto-acceptance for a specific set of users? Have anyone faced a similar situation ?